# Subscribing to topic throw compilation error

Tags: compilation, laserscan, topic, subscribe, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS users !

I'm trying to write a simple controller that takes LaserScan and directly send motor command (in Braitenberg's style), but I'm quite struggling with subscription to node. The subscription method is not recognized when *rosmaking* and I don't understand what's wrong as I think I doing that the same way as in [Writing a Publisher and Subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) or [Publishers and Subscribers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

Any hint would be welcome !

Here is the code :

---

**Class definition**

```
 #ifndef BRAITENBERG_CONTROLLER_H
 #define BRAITENBERG_CONTROLLER_H

 #include <iostream>
 #include <ros/ros.h>

 #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

 #include <tf/transform_listener.h>
 #include <tf/message_filter.h>
 #include <message_filters/subscriber.h>

 #include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>
 #include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

 namespace braitcontrol {

  class BrController
  {
     private :
        //! The node handle we'll be using
        ros::NodeHandle nh_;
        //! publishing to "/base_controller/command" topic
        ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub_;
        ros::Subscriber scan_filter_sub_;

         //message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> scan_filter_sub_;

        tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> * tf_filter_; 
        tf::TransformListener tf_;
    
        std::string target_frame_;

     public :
        BrController(ros::NodeHandle &nh);
    
        bool driveBraitenberg();
        sensor_msgs::LaserScan>& laser_ptr);
        void msgCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan & msg);

    };

}

#endif
```

---

**Class Implementation**

```
#include "braitenberg_controller.h"

using namespace braitcontrol;

BrController::BrController(ros::NodeHandle &nh) : target_frame_("/base_controller/command")
{
   /* Node handle that manage the node and provide publishing and subscribing function */
   nh_ = nh;

   /* Set up the publisher for the cmd_vel topic : we'll publish on this topic to drive the robot */
   cmd_vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/base_controller/command", 1);

   /* Same for subscriber */
   scan_filter_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("scan", 50, msgCallback); // Faulty line !!!
   //tf_filter_ = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(scan_filter_sub_, tf_, target_frame_, 10);    
}

 void BrController::msgCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan & msg)
 {
    std::cout << "Callback" << std::endl;
 }

 bool BrController::driveBraitenberg()
 {
    // Just driving robot according a constant rotation command
    //we are sending commands of type "twist" to drive the robot
    geometry_msgs::Twist base_cmd;
  

float cmd = 50.0;

    while(nh_.ok())
    {       
     base_cmd.angular.z = cmd;
         //publish the assembled command
         cmd_vel_pub_.publish(base_cmd);
    }

  return true;
}
    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //init the ROS node
  ros::init(argc, argv, "braitenberg_controller");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  BrController bControl(nh);
  bControl.driveBraitenberg();

  return 0;
}
```

---

And here is the error :

```
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pr2_braitenberg_controller.dir/src/braitenberg_controller.o
/home/renaudo/ros_workspace/pr2_braitenberg_controller/src/braitenberg_controller.cpp:
    In constructor ‘braitcontrol::BrController::BrController(ros::NodeHandle&)’:
/home/renaudo/ros_workspace/pr2_braitenberg_controller/src/braitenberg_controller.cpp:13: error:
    no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [5], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h:785: note:
    candidates are: ros::Subscriber   ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions&)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36200/subscribing-to-topic-throw-compilation-error/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-06-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Change the following

```
scan_filter_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("scan", 50, msgCallback);
```

to

```
scan_filter_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("scan", 50, &BrController::msgCallback, this);
```

And you have to remove ')' in the .h file at line num 38.

Hope it resolves the issue.

Thanks, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-11**:
Thanks  for answering ! I tried that but error is the same except that the third argument is not *"unresolved overloaded function type"* but *"void (braitcontrol::BrController::*)(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan&)"*. It is still asking for SubscriberOptions but  ...

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-11**:
... I saw examples without using this structure (and that are supposed to work even if I didn't run them). At least, this (giving the right pointer) is correcting another issue.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-11**:
I just updated my answer with "this". Try n let me know

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-11**:
It's now compiling but it seems that it's never receiving messages (even when remaped on /base_scan or /base_scan_throttled ). Laser are enabled with launching gmapping and checked with rViz. According to th Terminal output, only driveBraitenberg is executed and never the callback.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-11**:
Could you post this issue as a new question so that people will respond to it.

**Comment by [rouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/14871/rouch/) on 2014-04-16**:
Hi Erwan. i'm having exactly your last problem: my callback is never executed. how did you solved the issue?

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2014-04-16**:
Hello Rouch. I don't really remember what was the exact problem and the solution. From reading the code again, I guess it may be the lack of "ros::SpinOnce()" in the driveBraitenberg function. If that doesn't solve your problem, open  a new question with details, I'll give it a try.

**Comment by [rouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/14871/rouch/) on 2014-04-20**:
No, was exactly that the problem, i wasn't spinning the callback queue. Shame on me :) thank you for the answer!